# RoslynAnalyzer action for analyzing a String Literal

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to write a RoslynAnalayzer for validating Path formats.

I start with the VisualStudio template for RoslynAnalyzer, and I want to know which action should I register to analyze string literals?

(Currently, the `RegisterSymbolAction` get a `SymbolKind`, and I couldn't find a value for `SymbolKind` that give me a StringLiteral).

Comment: You probably want `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction` and to look for `SyntaxKind.StringLiteralToken`

Comment: @JoshVarty Why not as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have code like this:

```cs
var path = @"path\to\file";
```

You need to register an analyzer for [`SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxkind):

```cs
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression);
}

...

private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var literalNode = context.Node as LiteralExpressionSyntax;

...
```

---

About the `SyntaxKind.StringLiteralToken`, this not working for `var path = @"path\to\file"`.